# Cross-platform installer that install automatically the runtime

Tags: mono, gtk#

I'm developing a Desktop application using Mono and Gtk#.
Now I need to deploy this app.
I need to use a cross-platform (OsX, Windows, Linux) installer. I think that I will use Bitrock installbuilder but I need to know if it is possible to automatically install the Mono-Runtime and Mono-gtk# automatically If the machine does not have them.

My program is aimed at an audience of elderly, so it is *very very* important to build a easy-to-use installer. If the user's machine does not have Mono-runtime or Mono-Gtk# installed, the installer *must* install them automatically.

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a cross-platform installer is potentially an option, I don't think it is your best bet. Especially if you want to support all three platforms. It's more work, but using a different installer for each platform is generally your best bet.

NullSoft feels very comfortable on windows, and it's scripting is strong enough to embed other installers. Check their wiki for [details](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers).

On OS X, a native package should be used to install applications an libraries. I'm not sure exactly what implementation details there are, but [here](http://www.osxgnu.org/info/osxpackages.html) seems to have them. If additional functionality is needed, a bash script is always an option.

As far as installing on Linux, your best bets will always either be hand them the source code, or make it as simple as possible. A folder that can be unzipped into home, with a script to create the launcher file and check for yum, apt, and dpkg is probably good enough for most cases.